# MySQL - UPDATE query referring to another table

Tags: mysql

I need to update some records in one table by clause from another.

table_A - status to change

| ID | DID | status | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 29 | OK | X-9 |
| 2 | 29 | OK | X-8 |
| 3 | 29 | OK | X-6 |

table_B - clause

| v_1 | v_2 |
| --- | --- |
| X-9 | 2022-07-13 |
| X-8 | 2022-06-30 |
| X-6 | 2022-06-30 |

I tried by this query but doesnt work...

```
UPDATE
    table_A
SET
    table_A.status = "NOK"
FROM
    table_A AS table_A
    INNER JOIN table_B AS table_B
        ON table_A.value = table_B.v_1
WHERE
        table_A.DID = 29 
    AND table_A.status = "OK" 
    AND table_B.v_2 < NOW()
```

I will be grateful for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic syntax errors when using UPDATE query
Your query should be something like:

```
UPDATE
    table_A AS table_A
    INNER JOIN table_B AS table_B
        ON table_A.value = table_B.v_1
SET
    table_A.status = "NOK"
WHERE
        table_A.DID = 29 
    AND table_A.status = "OK" 
    AND table_B.v_2 < NOW()
```

Give it a try